# How to use #each for nested array with variable index

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

I want to walk through a nested array with Handlebars like this:

```
{{#each outerArray.[actual.key].innerArray}} <!-- Do something -->
```

If I write:

```
{{#each outerArray.[1].innerArray}} <!-- Do something -->
```

it works, but I neet a variable Index from my backbone.js model.

Answer (score 0):

I need to see your data to see how to place the variables in the template